# Why do I get an Undefined Variable: request in laravel

Tags: laravel

I got an error with my query, it seems that my `Request $request` variable can't be used inside the `function($quer){$query->}` below is my sample code.

```
Table1::addSelect(['PaymentStatus' => Table2::selectRaw('COUNT(*)')
        ->whereColumn('AccountNumber','Table1.AccountNumber')
        ->whereColumn('ServicePeriodEnd','Table1.ServicePeriodEnd')
        ])->whereNotExists(function($query){
            $query->select(DB::raw('*'))
            ->from('Table2')
            ->whereRaw('Table1.AccountNumber = Table2.AccountNumber')
            ->whereRaw('Table1.ServicePeriodEnd = Table2.ServicePeriodEnd')
            ->where('AccountNumber', $request->AccountNum); // this part gives an Undefined Variable: request
        })->where('AccountNumber', $request->AccountNum)
        ->orderBy('ServicePeriodEnd','desc')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $request variable can not be read from the function due to it's not been declared to be used in the function. Replace this line:

```
   ])->whereNotExists(function($query){
```

With this line

```
    ])->whereNotExists(function($query) use ($request) {
```

This is relatively new syntax btw. Example can be found at https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: oh yeah I forgot to add the `use ($request)` , Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

**Use request `use ($request)` in the callback function query**

`->whereNotExists(function($query) use ($request) {`

```
Table1::addSelect(['PaymentStatus' => Table2::selectRaw('COUNT(*)')
        ->whereColumn('AccountNumber','Table1.AccountNumber')
        ->whereColumn('ServicePeriodEnd','Table1.ServicePeriodEnd')
        ])->whereNotExists(function($query) use ($request) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('*'))
            ->from('Table2')
            ->whereRaw('Table1.AccountNumber = Table2.AccountNumber')
            ->whereRaw('Table1.ServicePeriodEnd = Table2.ServicePeriodEnd')
            ->where('AccountNumber', $request->AccountNum); // this part gives an Undefined Variable: request
        })->where('AccountNumber', $request->AccountNum)
        ->orderBy('ServicePeriodEnd','desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: I really did forgot to add the `use request`. btw thanks!